# How can I order the contours in an orderly manner from top to bottom from left to right?

Tags: java, android, opencv, computer-vision

I have to take shelf plans. I would like to order them as if it were a matrix where [0,0] was at the bottom left or top left.
I need this because there will be a database with coordinates to take something on the shelf.

But findContours takes the contours randomly and I don't know how to sort them.
How can I do?

I hope I was clear.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    Mat img = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0);
    Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, 100, 255, 3, true);
    Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, kernelSize);
    Imgproc.dilate(gray, gray, kernel);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, gray, new Size(3, 3), 0);
    List < MatOfPoint > contours = new ArrayList < MatOfPoint > ();
    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE,
        Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
    //For each contour found
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        //convert contours(i) from MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f
        MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new
        MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());
        double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true) * 0.05;
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);
        //convert back to MatOfPoint
        MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());
        //SORT POINTs

        //Get bounding rect of contour
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
        //draw enclosing rectangle
        if (rect.height > 200 && rect.width > 200)
            // Imgproc.rectangle(img,new Point(rect.x,rect.y),new 
            Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4);
        Imgproc.rectangle(img, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4);
    }
    return img;
}
```

Comment: can't help you with a java code example but in openCV with python i use `cv2.boundingRect` to get rectangles coordinates (as you did).
Then i sort the rectangles by their coordinates and use the indexes of the sorted rectangles to sort che contours array.

Comment: @s1rsimon How would you do it?  how would you sort in python the outline so as to then take the shelf [x, y] of the shelf? Could you explain it to me in C ++ ??